# Cutegram on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, telegram

I tried to install cutegram as written in the documentation, but i just get this.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aseman/desktop-apps
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cutegram
```

```
user@user-E205SA:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease [243 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease            
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty InRelease      
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89,2 kB]     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu zesty InRelease     
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty Release        
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 332 kB in 13s (25,2 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
user@user-E205SA:~$ sudo apt-get install cutegram
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package cutegram is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cutegram' has no installation candidate
```

If I install it manualy via .deb the app shows up, but do not open.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Cutegram](http://aseman.co/en/products/cutegram/) development and maintenance had been abandoned. 
The latest version available is 2.7.1, and it's been release in Jan 2016.

The [ppa:aseman/desktop-apps](https://launchpad.net/~aseman/+archive/ubuntu/desktop-apps) doesn't have any packages for the latest releases.
 The only currently supported release Cutegram is avalable for is Trusty - 14.04.
I'd recommend removing that PPA, as it's useless.

PS: Installing packages intended for another release is a hit and miss game, it may or may not work due to unmet dependencies or updated libs.

Comment: Yes, but still the "best" alternative telegram for ubuntu. there is no other, where u can use secure chat accept the pidgin-plugin "telegram-purple" - but this plugin is very weak and buggy. Cutegram also works on 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is obvious: the `ppa:aseman/desktop-apps` PPA does not have anything for Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file. 

Answer (score 0):

[The last distribution supported by that PPA is 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)](http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu/dists/). You can try to install the Wily version by running:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo mv aseman-ubuntu-desktop-apps-zesty.list aseman-ubuntu-desktop-apps-wily.list
sudo nano aseman-ubuntu-desktop-apps-wily.list
```

Replace all instances in the file of `zesty` with `wily`, then save it. Now run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cutegram
```

Comment: I tried, but shows me <pre>W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu wily InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: BA4DCD29162C7544D706080B801DC115C117080D
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aseman/desktop-apps/ubuntu wily InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
 </pre> Is there a way to enable it?